# How to record a video by using particular crop rectangular box in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am planning to achieve the following feature in my app.
Can you please let me know an idea or sample code?

[image]

I need to create the rectangular box and need to record that particular section only.

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apple restricted this feature for security reason. There is no directly API support to customize the camera frame. But you can capture the video and play as you need.

Comment: I am looking to build similar kind of approach ==> https://itunes.apple.com/app/id778576249?mt=8